# Circular shaped data for Local Search

Tags: c, algorithm, matlab, search, local

I am currently working on an implementation of a Local Search algorithm over an array of complex numbers in C. The point over which I run my algorithm are the following ones:

[image: Complex Numbers]

As you can see it on the figure, the numbers are spread in a circular shape over the complex plane.

Now, the first implementation of my algorithm is taking a random point in this space and tries to find the neighbours by computing the module over all the different points in the complex plane by running in a 1D complex array.

Once the neighbours have been found, the cost function is evaluated over the different neighbours and only the one that gives the best value is kept and the process is repeated again until the maximum of the cost function has been reached. This method is not really a Local Search because I could directly compute the cost function on all the different points in place of having to find the neighbours.

[image: Cost Values]

As you understand, the current way of doing it is not efficient at all and therefore I thought of moving to a 2D implementation.

The problem is that I don't know how  I could sort my complex numbers to have a 2D array in which I could know directly the neighbours instead of running through all the points?

Comment: Yes. In fact the data is extracted in matlab and processed in C. I will change the tags.

Comment: what is the purpose of the search?

Comment: The purpose of the search is to find the maximum cost value point in the second graph.